# Conditional automated web interation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a script that interacts with a webpage, uploads a file, submits it, and downloads the response.  Recently, the party that controls the website made some kind of change to it.  I am trying to adapt to the change, but I have a sticking point.  I am using java and selenium to open a Chrome browser.  The page opens.  There used to be three buttons - a reset button, an upload button, and a choose file button.  This is still the case part of the time.

However, sometimes when the site opens, only the first 2 buttons are there.  I found that if I manually click on the upload button, the page refreshes and the choose file button appears.  I am now trying to incorporate this into my code.  Here's the problem bit...

```
    driver.get("http://apps.gdgps.net/apps_file_upload.php");
    System.out.println("test a");
    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']"))!= null){
        System.out.println("test a - passed");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']")).click();
    }else{
        System.out.println("test a - failed");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='upload_button']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']")).click();
    }
```

So, I get the "test a" to print all the time.  If the choose file button is present, I see "test a - passed" and the file is uploaded.  If the button is not present, I do not see "test a - failed" and everything just hangs. The upload button is never pressed.

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  I experimented by moving the upload_button line above the if statement.  It runs independently.  What would be different when it's placed in the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't test for an element to be `null`. If you want to see if an element is present, you use `.findElements` (note the plural) and test if the returned collection is empty. If it's empty, no element was found.

```
driver.get("http://apps.gdgps.net/apps_file_upload.php");
System.out.println("test a");
List<WebElement> upload = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']"));
if (upload.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("test a - failed");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='upload_button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']")).click();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("test a - passed");
    upload.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your code is more elegant than mine.  It still does not click the upload button upon a fail, though.  A pass still works well, though.  Btw, it never prints "test a - failed."  Does that mean it's not finding a negative to the if statement and only recognizes a positive?

Comment: It's possible that in your recent runs with this code that the button was always there. You might need to add a wait, depending on the page, etc.

Comment: I have it waiting for up to 30 minutes.  It doesn't error out.  It just hangs there until I manually click the upload button.  Then it moves on.

Comment: The code I provided has no waits. It should either work immediately or fail immediately. The likely issue is with the code you are adding but I can't see that to comment.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ngsadmin\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: That's all that exists before your code.  Does that wait timer not apply to the if statement that you wrote?

Comment: Yes, you should get rid of the implicit wait. That's where the time is going. Implicit wait is not a good practice anyway. You should use explicit waits, `WebDriverWait`, as needed.